# Integral of $(\frac{3}{2}-(\frac{3}{2}-x^5)^5)^\frac{1}{5}$

Tags: calculus, integration

While solving another integral problem I was able to reduce it to this integral.

$$\int \left(\frac{3}{2}-\left(\frac{3}{2}-x^5\right)^5\right)^\frac{1}{5}dx$$

I am not sure how to solve it from here. I don't really see any obvious substitution I can perform. Is there some kind of trick I can employ?

The original problem was this: 
If,
$$f(x) = (4\sin^4(x) + 2\cos(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)-x^5)^\frac{1}{5}$$
Then calculate the indefinite integral
$$\int_{}^{}f(f(x)^5)dx$$

Comment: What’s the original problem you were doing, and how did you get here? It might be that your method just doesn’t work. By the way, this integral has no answer in terms of standard mathematical functions, according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%283%2F2+-+%283%2F2-x%5E5%29%5E5%29%29%5E%281%2F5%29).